# How to setup remote debug on initialization?

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish, payara

I'm trying to set up a remote debug properly. I have already set a remote debug and it works, but it not working on an application initialization stage, which means I can not see how a cache fills and so on. 
My environment: Payara 4 (it is Glassfish) and IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

How to make a correct setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suspend the JVM on remote debugging by using `suspend=y` which make the JVM to wait until the remote debugger is attached.

So the debugger's JVM options will be as below

Java 5-8

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

Java 9 and later

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005
```

Note: Adjust the port based on your settings.